# List of Sharepoint Lists

Tags: list, powershell, collection

I am trying to find a method of creating a list which contains the name of all other lists on the sharepoint site. The list would have to update itself based on the current state of the lists on the site.

Would a self-maintaining list like this be possible to make? Could a Powershell script be set to run every time a list is created or deleted to make the respective change in the master list? Could it be done in flows somehow?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: are you need any changes applied on the sub list items will be reflected to the master list ?

Comment: Is it not enough to look at the list of All Site Content showing only lists? URL would be like: <hostname>/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx?BaseType=0

Answer (score 1):

You can see all the lists and libraries of the current site from the site itself. In **Site Settings** under **Site Administration** we have a option Site Libraries and Lists which will list out all the Lists and Libraries of the current site.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
You can create List Event receivers to update your List. Below events will be fired when there will be operation on site like list is added/deleted.

ListAdded

ListDeleted

**Option 2** Another option which i can think of, though it might not be recommended way but below can be used.

Step 1  - Create a List X with required columns(manually) which will maintain data about all list and libraries.

Step 2 - Create a default view of list X which will display required data.(you can also use default view)

Step 3 - Write client side code to get all list and libraries and update/create/delete items in above list X.

Step 4 - Include calling of above client side code in default view of your List X before list data is rendered.

So every time you list view is displayed to end user, it will first make rest api call to get all list and libraries and update list items in List X and then display data.